# IF EXIST/IF NOT EXIST in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a little problem with the batch script I'm writing.

```
:Delete_File
cls
title Delete File
echo Welcome to the Utility Delete File!
echo Type the name of the file you want to delete:
echo.
set /p var=
echo.
echo I'm checking the existance of the file...
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000>nul
if EXIST %var% del %var%
if NOT EXIST %var% echo The file doesn't exist. Check for errors and try again. 
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1500>nul
set /p answer=1 - Go to Menu _ 2 - Go to Exit 
if %answer%==1 goto Menu
if %answer%==9 goto Exit
```

So, the problem is that when the file is founded, It gets deleted but then it shows the message in 12th string.
I need to show the message "The file was successfully deleted! Redirecting you to the Menu..."

```
echo The file was successfully deleted!
echo Redirecting you to the Menu...
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000>nul
goto Menu
```

I'm truly sorry for the bad syntax of the question, but I'm new.

Thanks for every response I get!

Federico.

Comment: You mean 12th line of code. The answer below solves your problem but think about the logic you were using and you could have solved it yourself. Flip flop the lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you having problem with else, you can use multiple labels, like:

```
if NOT EXIST %var% goto :DeleteFileMissing
del %var%
Goto :DeleteFileContinue

:DeleteFileMissing
echo The file doesn't exist. Check for errors and try again. 

:DeleteFileContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

Batch is really not the best language to do this kind of project in, but you should reverse the order of your IF EXIST and IF NOT EXIST lines. Once you delete the file in the IF EXIST line, the file no longer exists, and the IF NOT EXIST test immediately after will thus succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist %var% (
  del %var%
) else (
  echo The file doesn't exist. Check for errors and try again.
)
```

Comment: @F.Tinelli, Windows XP most certainly has `IF ELSE` capability.

Comment: @F.Tinelli, the `else` clause was included in `NT`. You have it.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for everyone response!